# Convert style and html to gmail capable

Tags: css, email, gmail, html-email, inline-styles

I tried many times on sending an html with style email to gmail, but it always destroy the style it expected look like in normal HTML. Anyone could kindly help me to convert it to gmail capable that must look exactly the same it should be? Thank you.

```html
<div style="display: flex;justify-content: center;">
<div class="container" style="font-family: 'Manrope-Regular';max-width: 600px;border-style: solid;border-color: #7E7E7E;position: relative;height: fit-content;border-width: 1px;">
    <img class="top-bg" src="https://saas-staging-wp.chatsmart.io/wp-content/uploads/revslider/slider-1/1-Path 842 (1).png" style="max-width: 255px;position: absolute;right: 0;">
    <img class="bottom-bg" src="https://saas-staging-wp.chatsmart.io/wp-content/uploads/revslider/slider-1/1-Path 841.png" style="position: absolute;left: 0;bottom: 0;max-width: 270px;">
    <div class="logo" style="font-family: 'Manrope-Regular';">
        <img src="https://chatsmart-saas.s3.ap-east-1.amazonaws.com/wp/images/2021/01/08030440/mobile-menu-logo.png" style="margin: 41px auto;display: block;">
    </div>
    <div class="content" style="font-family: 'Manrope-Regular';margin: 0 100px;">
        <p class="header" style="font-family: 'Manrope-Regular';">Hi  [first_name] [last_name],</p>
        <p class="para" style="font-family: 'Manrope-Regular';">Welcome to ChatSmart! Experience the powerful ChatSmart features to let you easily reach your customers. Not only increase customers loyalty through broadcast messages, but also lower abandon cart rate by supporting eCommerce platforms. Create your sales revenue by 24 / 7 answer customers' enquiries! 
        </p>
        <p class="para" style="font-family: 'Manrope-Regular';">
            <strong>Some popular resources which would be useful for you:</strong>
        </p>
        <ul>
            <li style="font-weight: 400;"><a href="https://youtu.be/tWrIxgg1VlE"><span style="font-weight: 400;">How to login &amp; connect WhatsApp? (Cantonese)</span></a></li>
            <li style="font-weight: 400;"><a href="https://youtu.be/5-kRHNZJqKY"><span style="font-weight: 400;">How to start the chat with your customer? (Cantonese)</span></a></li>
        </ul>
        <br>
        <p class="para" style="font-family: 'Manrope-Regular';">
            For more support, you may find below：
        </p>
        <ul>
            <li style="font-weight: 400;"><a href="https://userguide.chatsmart.io/"><span style="font-weight: 400;">ChatSmart User Guide (Traditional Chinese)</span></a></li>
            <li style="font-weight: 400;"><a href="https://wa.me/85267156250?text=%E6%88%91%E5%9C%A8ChatSmart%E9%9C%80%E8%A6%81%E5%8D%94%E5%8A%A9"><span style="font-weight: 400;">Technical Support</span></a></li>
        </ul>
        <br>
        <p class="para" style="font-family: 'Manrope-Regular';">Click below button to start your journey in ChatSmart!</p>
        <a class="button button-text" href="[link]" style="justify-content: center;display: flex;">
            <img style="max-width: 206px;" src="https://chatsmart-saas.s3.ap-east-1.amazonaws.com/wp/images/2021/01/21125343/login.png"/>
        </a>
        <br>
        <p class="para" style="font-family: 'Manrope-Regular';">More super practical content is on the way, stay tuned!</p>
        <br>
        <p class="para" style="font-family: 'Manrope-Regular';">Thanks,</p>
        <br>
        <p class="signature" style="font-family: 'Manrope-Regular';font-weight: bold;">
            ChatSmart Team<br>
            Your Best WhatsApp Marketing Platform
        </p>
        <br>
        <div class="soscial" style="font-family: 'Manrope-Regular';">
            <a href="https://www.facebook.com/chatsmart.io"><img src="https://chatsmart-saas.s3.ap-east-1.amazonaws.com/wp/images/2021/01/06145810/Group-764.png" style="margin-right: 20px;"></a>
            <a href="https://www.instagram.com/chatsmart.io/"><img src="https://chatsmart-saas.s3.ap-east-1.amazonaws.com/wp/images/2021/01/06150156/1-Group%20766.png" style="margin-right: 20px;"></a>
        </div>
        <br>
        <div class="footer" style="font-family: 'Manrope-Regular';text-align: center;font-size: 8px;margin-bottom: 20px;">
            ©2021 ChatSmart, Inc. All rights reserved.
        </div>
    </div>
</div>
</div>
```

Updated: Included a version of style and head block.

```html
<html>
    <head>
        <style>
            @font-face {
                font-family: 'Manrope-Regular';
                src: url('https://saas-staging.chatsmart.io/font/Manrope-Regular.ttf') format("opentype");
            }
            p, div {
                font-family: 'Manrope-Regular';
            }
            body{
                display: flex;
                justify-content: center;
            }
            .container {
                max-width: 600px;
                border-style: solid;
                border-color: #7E7E7E;
                position: relative;
                height: fit-content;
                border-width: 1px;
            }
            .top-bg {
                max-width: 255px;
                position: absolute;
                right: 0;
            }
            .bottom-bg {
                position: absolute;
                left: 0;
                bottom: 0;
                max-width: 270px;
                z-index: -1;
            }
            .logo img {
                margin: 41px auto;
                display: block;
            }
            .content {
                margin: 0 100px;
            }
            a.button {
                text-decoration: none;
            }
            .signature {
                font-weight: bold;
            }
            .soscial img {
                margin-right: 20px;
            }
            .footer {
                text-align: center;
                font-size: 8px;
                margin-bottom: 20px;
            }

        </style>
    </head>
    <body>
        <div class="container">
            <img class="top-bg" src="https://saas-staging-wp.chatsmart.io/wp-content/uploads/revslider/slider-1/1-Path 842 (1).png" />
            <img class="bottom-bg" src="https://saas-staging-wp.chatsmart.io/wp-content/uploads/revslider/slider-1/1-Path 841.png" />
            <div class="logo">
                <img src="https://chatsmart-saas.s3.ap-east-1.amazonaws.com/wp/images/2021/01/08030440/mobile-menu-logo.png" />
            </div>
            <div class="content">
                <p class="header">Hi  [first_name] [last_name],</p>
                <p class="para">Welcome to ChatSmart! Experience the powerful ChatSmart features to let you easily reach your customers. Not only increase customers loyalty through broadcast messages, but also lower abandon cart rate by supporting eCommerce platforms. Create your sales revenue by 24 / 7 answer customers' enquiries! 
                </p>
                <p class="para">
                    <strong>Some popular resources which would be useful for you:</strong>
                </p>
                <ul>
                    <li style="font-weight: 400;"><a href="https://youtu.be/tWrIxgg1VlE"><span style="font-weight: 400;">How to login &amp; connect WhatsApp? (Cantonese)</span></a></li>
                    <li style="font-weight: 400;"><a href="https://youtu.be/5-kRHNZJqKY"><span style="font-weight: 400;">How to start the chat with your customer? (Cantonese)</span></a></li>
                </ul>
                <br/>
                <p class="para">
                    For more support, you may find below：
                </p>
                <ul>
                    <li style="font-weight: 400;"><a href="https://userguide.chatsmart.io"><span style="font-weight: 400;">ChatSmart User Guide (Traditional Chinese)</span></a></li>
                    <li style="font-weight: 400;"><a href="https://wa.me/85267156250?text=%E6%88%91%E5%9C%A8ChatSmart%E9%9C%80%E8%A6%81%E5%8D%94%E5%8A%A9"><span style="font-weight: 400;">Technical Support</span></a></li>
                </ul>
                <br/>
                <p class="para">Click below button to start your journey in ChatSmart!</p>
                <a class="button button-text" href="[link]" style="justify-content: center;display: flex;">
                    <img style="max-width: 206px;" src="https://chatsmart-saas.s3.ap-east-1.amazonaws.com/wp/images/2021/01/21125343/login.png"/>
                </a>
                <br/>
                <p class="para">More super practical content is on the way, stay tuned!</p>
                <br/>
                <p class="para">Thanks,</p>
                <br/>
                <p class="signature">
                    ChatSmart Team<br/>
                    Your Best WhatsApp Marketing Platform
                </p>
                <br/>
                <div class="soscial">
                    <a href="https://www.facebook.com/chatsmart.io"><img src="https://chatsmart-saas.s3.ap-east-1.amazonaws.com/wp/images/2021/01/06145810/Group-764.png" /></a>
                    <a href="https://www.instagram.com/chatsmart.io/"><img src="https://chatsmart-saas.s3.ap-east-1.amazonaws.com/wp/images/2021/01/06150156/1-Group%20766.png" /></a>
                </div>
                <br/>
                <div class="footer">
                    ©2021 ChatSmart, Inc. All rights reserved.
                </div>
            </div>
        </div>
    </body>
</html>
```

[image: Gmail client break the style]

Comment: Can you share the entirety of your HTML code ? (with the `<head>` and the `<style>` tags)

Answer (score 1):

You need a complete redesign. You can't develop emails like websites, because there are lots of restrictions. For example, you need to write code inline, not rely on embedded CSS (within `<style>...</style>`); and things like divs and flexbox are temperamental - see caniemail.com.

Check out any HTML email template, or HTML email course, and then make sure you test in a variety of email clients on a variety of devices.